# Is it Possible to manipulate GPIO pins via a Configuration File (.json, .ini et.al)

Tags: gpio, pi-2

#### Device and Firmware

- Raspberry Pi - 2 and Debian Wheezy 7.10/7.11

I have a `config.json` or `config.ini` file which I send to the Pi in the form of a compressed file with other files (in `.tar`)

At the Pi I would have a triggering mechanism (using `inotify-tools`) which when receives the compressed file, *untars* it and then runs a **python** script to parse through the information.

#### `config` File

```
{
"pins":{

    "20": 1,
    "21":0
 },

 "files":{

      "Pi-1": "file1",
      "Pi-2": "file2"
   }
}
```

The **keys** in the above mentioned `config.json` file mention the following:

- GPIO Pin 20 must be **High**
- GPIO Pin 21 must be **Low**

Is this possible to set via the `rpi.gpio` feature for **Python** or are there some ready made implementations that some one has in mind or uses with Pis?

### Scenario

I am using a **Multicasting** scenario where I want to send files to many Pis within an ad-hoc network. This is needed since I cannot **ssh** into each Pi and send files and set the GPIOs individually since this will consume a lot of time (I am expecting at least 50 Pis). **SSH** is TCP based and hence broadcasting/ multicasting a bunch of files is not possible in general, hence I shifted my focus on **UDP** and there is something called as **Fountain Codes** which is an FEC based technique to distribute data(files) within a  network. There are a lot of other reasons why I do not use TCP which are beyond the point of this question.

I have an implementation ready for the above mentioned FEC technique where I take one file and distribute it all the Pis that are a part of the Multicast group. As mentioned before I need to configure some GPIO pins on Pis. This configuration varies from Pi to Pi hence a configuration file is needed to specify which Pi will have which settings and which file for further operation.

#### Reasons for a tar file

it consists of :

- a `config` file
- numerous files for different Pis (which file belongs to which Pi is mentioned in `config` file)

Hence I compress the whole *Pack* into a `tar` and then *untar* it at the Pis.

Comment: will update my question for better clarity of the situation

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into Chef (chef.io), and Puppet (https://puppet.com/) both of which provide the tools and services to allow deployment of particular configuration to multiple clients. I doubt that either would have (today) a recipe for configuring the GPIO pins, that would likely be something you'd have to add.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a program to do this.

I'm not aware of any existing programs which do what you want, possibly because it seems an odd way to go about doing things.

Comment: Well think of the scenario as many Pis and each Pi receiving this file but maybe with different GPIO pins values. Logging into each Pi and setting this up would be quite tedious hence just to automate the whole bunch I though of a config file.

Comment: *Using* json doesn't seem odd although expecting that there is pre-existing software to process a configuration scheme you dreamed up seems odd to the point of absurdity.  As joan says, obviously yes you could write a program to process the protocol you have invented, and there is also obviously a very large spectrum of other equally reasonable ways to do this.

Comment: Yes, you are both right, I'm just a bit set in my ways.  A simple piece of Python could consume the JSON, e.g. `import json; f = open(FILE, "r"); records = json.load(f); f.close();`.  The rest you could implement in a few lines of code.  Probably a half hour job to write and test.

Comment: You might want to look into Chef (https://www.chef.io/). Which provides the tools and services to allow deployment of particular configuration to multiple clients. I doubt that it would have (today) a recipe for configuring the GPIO pins, that would likely be something you'd have to add.

Comment: @KenHughes You could make that an answer.